# How do you check whether a range contains a subset of another range?

Tags: ruby, range

If I have two ranges that overlap:

```
x = 1..10
y = 5..15
```

When I say:

```
puts x.include? y
```

the output is:

```
false
```

because the two ranges only overlap partially.

But if I want it to be "true" when there is partial overlap between two ranges, how would I write that? In other words I need a way to know when one range contains a subset of another range. I assume there's an elegant way to write this in Ruby but the only solutions I can think of are verbose.

Comment: The output is `false` because the following is false: `x.begin <= y and y <= x.end` --- _not_ because they only partially overlap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful using this with large ranges but this is an elegant way to do it:

```
(x.to_a & y.to_a).empty?
```

Comment: This is a O(N) memory and time vs @MarkusQ's O(1) way.

Comment: And isn't really usable when instead of number you have *time* ranges ;)

Answer (score 64):

The efficient way is to compare the limits

```
(x.first <= y.last) and (y.first <= x.last)
```

Comment: Why is this more efficient than converting to an array? Does converting to an array use a lot of resources?

Comment: Okay, this is way better than mine!

Comment: Converting it to an array makes an array and fills it with values, then does the same for the second array, then searches the two arrays for matching items.  set x = 10000000..20000000 and y = 30000000..40000000 and time the two methods to see what I mean.

Comment: You can obtain a calling style as in the question by extending `Range` [like this](https://gist.github.com/4210878), to give `puts x.overlaps? y` and get `true`

Comment: On my own I have been thinking about it on my own, and couldn't come up with the solution that uses less than 4 conditionals. Simplicity rules!

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Ruby 2.6, you can use [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) with another `Range`.

```
(1..5).cover?(2..3)     #=> true
(1..5).cover?(0..6)     #=> false
(1..5).cover?(1...6)    #=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also convert the ranges to [sets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html), since you're basically doing set intersection here. Might be easier if you are dealing with more than two ranges.

```
x = (1..10).to_set
y = (5..15).to_set
!(x & y).empty? #returns true (true == overlap, false == no overlap)
```

Answer (score 2):

This method can be used to test overlap between multiple ranges in an efficient way:

```
def range_overlap?(ranges)
  sorted_ranges = ranges.sort
  sorted_ranges.each_cons(2).each do |r1, r2|
    return true if r2.first <= r1.last
  end
  return false
end


def test(r)
  puts r.inspect, range_overlap?(r)
  puts '================'
  r = r.reverse
  puts r.inspect, range_overlap?(r)
  puts '================'
end


test [[1,9], [10, 33]]
test [[1,10], [5, 8]]
test [[1,10], [10, 33]]
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case the ranges were objects with start and end dates so cover method wouldn't do. The other methods (transforming to arrays) would be to memory expensive. Your method is efficient and fast. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a range includes either the beginning or the end of a second range, then they overlap.

```
(x === y.first) or (x === y.last)
```

is the same as this:

```
x.include?(y.first) or x.include?(y.last)
```

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699448/ruby-how-do-you-check-whether-a-range-contains-a-subset-of-another-range#comment19657429_1337373) to see why that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I want it to be "true" when there is partial overlap between two ranges, 
>   how would I write that?

You can convert the ranges to an array, and use the `&` operator (*conjunction)*. This returns a new array with all the elements occuring in both arrays. If the resulting array is not empty, that means, that there are some overlapping elements:

```
def overlap?(range_1, range_2)
  !(range_1.to_a & range_2.to_a).empty?
end
```

Comment: This seems like the most intuitive solution.

Comment: @Chris -- It may be "the most intuitive" but 1) it's ridiculously inefficient and 2) it only works on integer ranges, so I wouldn't advise using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for overlap, then I'd just do

```
(x.include? y.first) or (x.include? y.last)
```

as one range will have to include at least one of the ends of the other.  This is more intuitive to me than the accepted conjuction answer, though not quite as efficient as MarkusQ's limit comparison.

Comment: This only covers the case where they *partially* overlap. Given `x = 3..6` and `y = 1..10`, your code would return false, but the two ranges do indeed overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has [Range#overlaps?](http://apidock.com/rails/Range/overlaps%3F)

```
def overlaps?(other)
  cover?(other.first) || other.cover?(first)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Some helpful enumerable methods:

```
# x is a 'subset' of y
x.all?{|n| y.include? n}
# x and y overlap
x.any?{|n| y.include? n}
# x and y do not overlap
x.none?{|n| y.include? n}
# x and y overlap one time
x.one?{|n| y.include? n}
```